# no static directory was shown in resource folder in spring-boot project? I have install the latest version 3.2.3?what was the issue?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, web-applications, xmlhttprequest

I am beginner with Spring Boot. I found no static folder to place html files.

While executing the project, it was displaying the following errors:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.2.3:run (default-cli) on project hello-spring: Process terminated with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Moreover, I am still getting the white label error when I have placed the `index.html` file in resource directory.